# What is the Height of EVA 01 as shown in the Rebirth series?

Tags: evangelion, mecha

In the original Evangelion series, the height of the EVA units was something between 40 and 95 meters tall. It changed back and forth and caused lots of controversy.

The rebuild series of movies seem to be more consistent with the mecha size. Also there are several shots of the mecha near real-life objects.

So, using the Rebirth shots (i.e. ignoring outdated source material), what is the height of the EVA 01?

Answer (score 3):

As you've already identified, the Evas are inconsistently portrayed, often shifting in size between scenes as the script requires, ranging between 40 metres when the characters need to run/jump/climb on them, up to a maximum of about 80-90 metres when they're moving around Tokyo-3 or fighting against the Angels.

Gainax did release the image below as part of the DVD extras relating to the *Rebuild* series. As you can see, it has a width and height scale.

[image]

Comment: I don't speak Japanese so the meaning of the other writing at the bottom of the image isn't known. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, Google Translate gives: Were placed in a grid of 10m each to form setting, contrast reference. Image by way of Anno Hideaki was using, vol wrote also the size of the car or train or hierarchy of building

Comment: That is why I am only interested in rebirth or later material. From watching the movies, it seemed less random. Also I need reliable info to spite the Pacific Rim groupies.

Comment: @Mindwin - There is no reliable material when it comes to cartoon monsters. They're as big/small as the story requires.

Comment: 75 meters to the head and 80 to the shoulder then?

Comment: @FernandoJoseFerrada  - On that scale.